# paper-radio-group allows multi select with dom-repeat

Tags: polymer-2.x

The user is allowed to select multiple options eventhough the name is different in the `paper-radio-button`. How can this be fixed. I only want one option to be selectable at a time

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items=[[_calculateQuestionOptions(index)]]>
<paper-radio-group>
<paper-radio-button name="{{_calculateId(index)}}">[[item.questionOption]]</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
</template>
```